# How to make a choice field from many to many related classes in django?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a django web project. There are products for sales points. The points can have similar and different products to sale. So, i have created many to many relationship between them.

```
class SalesPoint(models.Model):
    pointID = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    myStr = str(self.pointID) + "ID'li nokta"
    return myStr


class Product(models.Model):
    productID = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Kaydedilecek ürünün ID'si", default=0)
    productName = models.TextField(verbose_name="Kaydedilecek ürünün adı")

    salesPoint = models.ManyToManyField(SalesPoint, verbose_name="Nokta ID", blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productName
```

Then I have a web page asking the user what product wants to be predicted. In this page, i want to create choice fields, and first i want to ask user which point he/she wants, then according to this point, i want to show available products(products that only belong to that sales point) to user. How can i make it? Here is my querying page module.

```
class SalesPrediction(models.Model):


    whichPoint = models.ForeignKey(SalesPoint, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    whichProduct = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
```

However, this show all the products and points, i want to show only related points and products.

Comment: You want a dependent dropdown? See [How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django (Simple is Better than Complex)](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i want to do.